# Single line while loop updating array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, while-loop, scripting

I am trying to build a while loop that updates the values in an array but I keep getting a command not found error.

```
i=1
bool=true
declare -a LFT
declare -a RGT
while read -r line; do
  ${LFT[$i]}=${line:0:1}; ${RGT[$i]}=$(wc -l < temp$i.txt);
  if [ ${LFT[$i]} -ne ${RGT[$i]} ]; then
    $bool=false;
  fi;
  ((i=i+1));
done<output2.txt
```

The file I am reading from contains a single digit on each line, and I want to fill the array LFT with each entry being the digit. The array RGT should be filled with the line counts of files denoted temp*.txt. And I want to test to make sure each entry of these two arrays are the same.

However, I keep getting an error: command =# not found, where # is whatever digit is on the line in the file. Am I assigning values to the arrays incorrectly? Also, I get the error: command true=false not found. I am assuming this has something to do with assigning values to the boolean.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on these lines:

```
${LFT[$i]}=${line:0:1}; ${RGT[$i]}=$(wc -l < temp$i.txt);
```

Change it to:

```
LFT[$i]=${line:0:1}; RGT[$i]=$(wc -l < temp$i.txt);
```

Valid assignment in shell should be:

```
var=<expression>
```

rather than

```
$var=<expression> ## this will be interpreted by the shell as a command
```

---

This is one of the common mistakes Bash programmers do.  More [Bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) here.

Comment: Wow, that was such a simple fix. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way of debugging to find out where the problems lie, or do you just know from experience?

Comment: Some of these things come with practice.  However, you can always pass your code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ - it is a wonderful tool.  And SO is a wonderful place for learning about Bash, among many other things.

Comment: @SeanMorgan You can use the `-u` and `-e` options when launching Bash.  The `-u` option causes errors on attempts at expanding unassigned variables, and should be used all the time : it requires explicit assignment of all variables, but misspelling variable names is to easy and hard to debug that that this is a good thing overall.  `-e` will cause the script to fail on any command returning a non-zero result.  Due to some limitations it cannot serve as a general error handling mechanism (it can fail in places you would not want it to for good reasons), but for debugging it can help.