# Adding value to an associative array named after a variable

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, associative

I need your help with a `bash >= 4` script I'm writing.

I am retrieving some files from remote hosts to back them up.
I have a for loop that iterate through the hosts and for each one tests connection and the start a function that retrieves the various files.

My problem is that I need to know what gone wrong (and if), so I am trying to store OK or KO values in an array and parse it later.

This is the code:

```
...
for remote_host in $hosts ; do
    short_host=$(echo "$remote_host" | grep -o '^[^.]\+')
    declare -A cluster
    printf "INFO: Testing connectivity to %s...   " "$remote_host"
    if ssh -q "$remote_host" exit ; then
        printf "OK!\n"
        cluster[$short_host]="Reacheable"
        mkdir "$short_host"
        echo "INFO: Collecting files ..." 
        declare -A ${short_host}
        objects1="/etc/krb5.conf /etc/passwd /etc/group /etc/fstab /etc/sudoers /etc/shadow"
        for obj in ${objects1} ; do
            if file_retrieve "$user" "$remote_host" "$obj" ; then
->              ${short_host}=["$obj"]=OK
            else
                ${short_host}=["$obj"]=KO

            fi
        done
...
```

So I'm using an array named `cluster` to list if the nodes were reacheable, and another array - named after the short name of the node - to list OK or KO for single files.
On execution, I got the following error *(line 130 is the line I marked with the arrow above)*:

`./test.sh: line 130: ubuntu01=[/etc/krb5.conf]=OK: command not found`

I think this is a synthax error for sure, but I can't fix it. I tried a bunch of combinations without success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array name is contained in a variable `short_list`, you need `eval` to make the assignment work:

```
${short_host}=["$obj"]=OK
```

Change it to:

```
eval ${short_host}=["$obj"]=OK
eval ${short_host}=["$obj"]=OK
```

---

Similar posts:

[Single line while loop updating array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053783/single-line-while-loop-updating-array/42053930#42053930)

Comment: Thanks, but `short_host` isn't the name of the array, actually. The name of the array is the short name of the node, and since I'm inside a for loop, this changes on iteration. That's why I refer to it as a variable, using the $ sign. If I don't do it, it is creating an array named `short_host`, isn't it ? Am I misunderstanding it ?

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day ! I have to say that I guessed about eval already, but I read on stackoverflow that eval is evil (literally), so I wasn't sure about it!. Thanks again !

Comment: `eval` is not really an evil if you control the string that is being passed into it.